# how to use single quotations inside a transact sql statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i want use single quotations inside a transact sql statement, then execute that statement.

for example my query is:

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = '1'
```

now i want use like this:

```
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = '1' '
Execute (@SQLQuery)
```

this not work, and this error occurred :

> Invalid column name '1'

I know problem is quotations in left and right side of the 1

this is a sample and i want use of this way to a large query

of course, i want use local variable instead for example '1' and my local variable is varchar

any idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just escape the quotes:

change

```
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = '1' '
```

to

```
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = ''1'' '
```

** Edit **

To include a local variable in the result, you could updated your query like this:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(200)
DECLARE @tmpInt int

SET @tmpInt = 2
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = ' + 
     convert(varchar, @tmpInt) + ' '
```

Comment: thanks, this work for value '1', but when i use local variable (for example @Id), no record returned. like this: ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = '' ' + @Id + ' '' '.  of course, my variable is varchar

Comment: It would have been better to specify that you actually wanted to use a local variable in your original question.

Comment: Updated the answer - just need to convert your variable to ensure that you are dealing with the correct types. You'd probably also want to look at using parameters rather than dynamic sql.

Answer (score 5):

Double the single quotes in the quote!

```
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = ''1'' '
```

Answer (score 4):

Use double ticks to escape them:

```
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = ''1'' '
Execute (@SQLQuery)
```

If you want to use a local variable as you mention in your comment, you can do this:

```
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
Declare @Id AS NVarchar(3)

SET @Id = '1'
SET @SQLQuery = ' Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id= ''' + @Id  + ''''
Execute (@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: i've used from this way, but not worked, and no records returned

Answer (score 2):

wrap the one single quote in to more like `'''` and the tics will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

To make a more reader-friendly code I use a variable for the single quote:

```
Declare @chrSQ char(1) = CHAR(39); --Single quote

SET @SQLQuery = 'Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = ' + @chrSQ + @Id + @chrSQ + ';'
```

/Flemming

Answer (score -1):

Try using double-quotes instead:

```
SET @SQLQuery = "Select * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Id = '" + @Id + "'"
```

Comment: double-quotes not work for create statements in t-sql, and allowed character is single-quotes